# What happens to the opened resources in Thread.yield , sleep and wait methods in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked in an Interview, about Multi-threading
What will happen to the opened resources in multi-threading if we call Thread.yield() or sleep(100000) or wait() methods after Opening the resource.
Will it get closed or it will be in Open ?
Please help me in understand Multi-threading.

Comment: What're the "opened resources" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep(100000)` causes the thread to definitely stop executing for the given amount of time. So all your open resources will remain open until then.

`yield()` method pauses the currently executing thread temporarily giving a chance to the remaining waiting threads of the same priority to execute. If there is no waiting thread or all the waiting threads have a lower priority then the same thread will continue its execution. So assuming your thread gets priority, the open resources will get closed. Otherwise, they can remain in open state.

`wait()` says “I’m done with my CPU timeslice. Don’t give me another timeslice until someone calls notify().” As with sleep(), the OS won’t even try to schedule your task unless someone calls notify() or one of a few other wakeup scenarios occurs. And so your open resources will remain open unless notify gets called and the open resources are closed.

Comment: Please help, to accept this answer. So in order to call sleep,notify and wait , is it a best practice to close resources and open resource when control comes back to the Thread ?